# Creating GeoJSON symbolization for points by name in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, color

I have a GeoJSON with several hundreds objects and I add it on Leaflet map. I want to create another symbolization for some object. But I don't understand how to change color and size for some of the object using their names. Could anybody help me?

My code looks like this:

```js
var centers = '{% url "centers" %}';
$.getJSON(centers, function (data) {
  L.geoJson(data, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latLng, options)
      },
      style: function (feature, layer) {
          return {
              'radius': 5,
              'color': 'DarkSlateGrey'
          };
      },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          layer.addEventListener("click", () => {
              layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.nameobject);
          })
      }
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter some features with some names to change their style properties and for the other assign another style

```
particular_names = ['particular1', 'particular2', 'particular3'];
style: function (feature, layer) {
    if (particular_names.includes(feature.properties.nameobject))
        return {
            'radius': 5,
            'color': 'DarkSlateGrey'
        };
    else {
        return {
            'radius': 2,
            'color': 'Red'
        };
    }
},
```

Imagining you have a column `myval` where you have the radius in your GeoJSON properties, you could

```
style: function (feature, layer) {
    return {
        'radius': feature.properties.myval * 2,
        'color': 'DarkSlateGrey'
    };
},
```